# randomly thrown LineUnavailableException

Tags: java, audio, wav

I want to add some sounds to my game but sometimes it throws LineUnavailableException

```
line with format PCM_SIGNED 22050.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported
```

This exception appears really randomly - for example it plays the same sound ten times and at the next attempt the exception is thrown.

For playing sounds I use following code:

```
private void playSound(String path) {     
        AudioInputStream audio = null;
        try {

            audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audio);
            clip.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameLogic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameLogic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameLogic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                audio.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GameLogic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried other sounds with other format (22kHz, 8bit, mono, 1B/frame), but without a change. Every sound is in WAV.

Can you please help me with this problem? Thanks!